# How to watch idle in ionic2 and angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I wanna watch idle for input box, mouse event and entire page..if 5 min idle, I wanna do auto logout and go to initial log in page using ionic2
My ionic2 info is

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Answer (score 5):

install typescript first,
**npm install -g typescript@2.0.0** 
second install ng-idle
**npm install --save @ng-idle/core @ng-idle/keepalive angular2-moment**

import ng-idle in app.module.ts
 **import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';**

```
imports: [
NgIdleKeepaliveModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)  ],
```

declare idle in typescript file which you wanna use. e.g:home.ts

```
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
export class HomePage {

idleState = 'Not started.';
timedOut = false;
min:any;
sec;any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,public idle: Idle) { }


 ionViewDidLoad() {
this.idle.setIdle(5);  //after 5 sec idle
this.idle.setTimeout(5*60);  //5min countdown
this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

this.idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'No longer idle.');
this.idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
  this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
  this.timedOut = true;
  this.navCtrl.pop();  //go to logout page after 5 min idle.
});
this.idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle!');
this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => {


    var data=countdown/60;
    this.min=data.toString().split('.')[0];
    this.sec=     parseFloat(0+'.'+data.toString().split('.')[1])*60;
    this.sec=  (Math.round(this.sec * 100) / 100);
    console.log(countdown)

  this.idleState = 'You'll logout in ' + this.min+' min ' +this.sec+'  seconds!';
});
   this.reload();
  }
  reload() {
    this.idle.watch();
    this.idleState = 'Started.';
    this.timedOut = false;
  }
}
```

in home.html

```
 <p><strong>{{idleState}}</strong></p>
<button (click)="reset()" *ngIf="timedOut">Reload</button>
```

it'll work as count down till 5 min.

[image]

Comment: It is not working as expected, when timeout is longer and device is sleep/locked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular < v.6, use

```
npm install --save @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15
npm install --save @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.15
```

if you are using angular v.6 , use

```
npm install --save @ng-idle/core
npm install --save @ng-idle/keepalive
```